# How to find probability that items belong to particular group?

Tags: probability

There are 100 products: 50 - from I group, 45 - II group and 5 from III group.
Randomly picking 2 products. How to find the probability that there are 2 picked from I group or 2 picked from II group? 
Looking in events: I, I or II, II, not I, II or II, I

Comment: Looks straightforward. How are you stuck on this?

Comment: I thought count of all possible events is C(100, 2) but my calculator can't calculate it, so I think I'm looking not right way at this.

Comment: You're on the right way. First express the probability using:  `(number of favorable events) / (number of total events)`

Comment: And C(100, 2) is not that large. However, you may use [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100+choose+2) as calculator

Comment: $C(100, 2) = 100\times 101 / 2 = 5050$.  No cases will satisfy I and II as you are only picking two items

Comment: As I found out that $C(100,2) = 4950$ I already knew that my searching probability is $(C(50,2)+C(45,2)) / 4950$. My problem is solved, answer is $443/990$

Comment: Yes that looks correct!

Comment: "*I thought count of all possible events is C(100,2) but my calculator can't calculate it*"   Often in an educational setting, it is preferable **not** to evaluate binomial coefficients and the like.  An answer of $\dfrac{\binom{50}{2}+\binom{45}{2}}{\binom{100}{2}}$ is much more preferable to me than an answer of $\frac{443}{990}$ in terms of verifying the correctness of a solution as the answer itself gives an idea as to the thought process and logic involved in having arrived at that answer.  Of course, do as your teacher asks and evaluate if they say to.

Comment: @GoodnightJess if you're looking for numerical answer you could completely avoid C's and work using probabilities alone: $$(\frac{50}{100})^2 + (\frac{45}{100})^2$$

Comment: @pooja that answer would have assumed that we are selecting *with* replacement and is not the same answer as what has been discussed elsewhere in this thread.  It is heavily implied that we are selecting *without* replacement.  The answer without replacement of course being $\frac{50\cdot 49 + 45\cdot 44}{100\cdot 99}$ or however else you prefer to rearrange things

Comment: Ah right! with out replacement the following should do $$\frac{50}{100}\frac{49}{99} +\frac{45}{100}\frac{44}{99} $$

Answer (score 0):

> Randomly picking 2 products. How to find the probability that there
>   are 2 picked from group I

First, write out the equation then see if you can simplify. The general equation for probability is $\frac{successful}{possible}$ events. The successful events for 2 balls from group I can be expressed as C(50,2) since there are 2 balls chosen from the 50 possible balls from group I. The number of all possible events is expressed as C(100,2) since there are 2 balls chosen from a total of 100 across all 3 groups. So, we can combine the values together and solve for the probability of 2 balls chosen from group I: 
$$\frac{C(50,2)}{C(100,2)}$$
To reduce this fraction, we can plug in the equation for a combination
$$C(n,r)=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$$
$$\frac{\frac{50!}{2!(50-2)!}}{\frac{100!}{2!(100-2)!}}$$
Then, we can reduce and cancel out to get a value that is much easier to cancel out
$$=\frac{\frac{50\times49\times48!}{2!\times48!}}{\frac{100\times99\times98!}{2!\times98!}}$$
$$=\frac{\frac{50\times49}{2!}}{\frac{100\times99}{2!}}$$
$$=\frac{50\times49}{100\times99}$$
$$=\frac{49}{2\times99}$$
$$=\frac{49}{198}$$